# Count rows for each latest status of tickets

Tags: postgresql, count, greatest-n-per-group

```
 ticket_number |          datetime          | status
---------------+----------------------------+---------
             1 | 2020-08-03 03:52:58.048196 | replied
             1 | 2020-08-02 19:55:49.121455 | new
             2 | 2020-07-30 03:52:58.048196 | pending
             2 | 2020-07-28 20:15:41.213842 | replied
             2 | 2020-07-26 03:52:58.482911 | new
             3 | 2020-06-17 19:55:49.394628 | closed
             3 | 2020-06-14 03:52:58.513141 | replied
             3 | 2020-06-11 19:55:49.242859 | new
             4 | 2020-05-14 07:13:50.527481 | new
             5 | 2020-05-13 11:24:38.558921 | new
```

The above table ordered by `datetime`. After ordering I need to group by `ticket_number` so that each ticket appears only once, and pick the `status` for the latest `datetime` per ticket. Then I need to count rows for each `status`.

Ticket 1 would have a status of replied - replied_count = 1,
Ticket 2 would have a status of pending - pending_count = 1,
Ticket 3 would have a status of closed - closed_count = 1,
Ticket 4 would have a status of new - new_count = 1,
Ticket 5 would have a status of mew - new_count = 2

Expected Result:

```
replied_count  |  pending_count  |  closed_count  |  new_count
---------------+-----------------+----------------+------------
             1 |               1 |              1 |          2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                     ticket_number, 
                     FIRST_VALUE(status) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_number 
                                               ORDER BY datetime DESC) last_status 
              FROM test )
SELECT last_status, COUNT(last_status) 
FROM cte
GROUP BY last_status
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a52879d1563a0dda6acbf0a7b69d731e)

for to obtain needed statistic in vertical form. If you need pivotted output strictly then use CROSSTAB() or similar, or emulate it using 4 CASEs.

Comment: This is brilliant. I tried so many different ways before coming here and wasted hours of time, and your solution far outperforms what I was doing (multiple subqueries with multiple inner joins). Love this thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster, yet:

```sql
SELECT status, count(*)
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (ticket_number) status
   FROM   test
   ORDER  BY ticket_number, datetime DESC
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ed536e1bddbe186fd9dae061e4c6627b)*

Assuming `datetime` is defined `NOT NULL`.
See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

If there are *many* rows per ticket, one of these techniques will be (much) faster, yet:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

A table `ticket` with one row per relevant ticket would help.